# Flutter - State Management and Providers

Tags: flutter

I am really struggling to get my head around state management. I understand that I can use Providers to pass this data to widgets with listeners but I can't seem to get anything working.

So far I have created a simple example where the user can change the wheels on a car. The images for the wheels have been stored in a list.

Is it possible to use a provider to access the index of the list and change the outcome accordingly?

I have added Providers in the dependencies of the pubspec.yaml.

main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './car.dart';
import './buttons.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            car(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Buttons(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Car:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class car extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return carState();
  }
}

class carState extends State<car> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var wheelImage = [
      Image.asset('assets/wheel1.png'),
      Image.asset('assets/wheel2.png'),
    ];
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/golf.png'), //car
        wheelImage[0], //wheel
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Buttons:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Buttons extends StatelessWidget {
  const Buttons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Wheel 1')),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Wheel 2')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Provider initial attempt:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WheelCounter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  
  void wheel1Choose() {
    _count = 0;
  }
  void wheel2Choose() {
    _count = 1;
  }
}
```

Where would I go about adding the provider code in this example?

Comment: Haven't you created any provider class for the logic?

Comment: I did try but I haven't included here because it would have been wrong.

Comment: If you don't post it then you might get a answer even but how will you get to know that what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Sorry  I can't seem to get the comment to display the code in the correct way.

Comment: Yes, you have edit your question but don't worry someone has answered just check it out if it works

Comment: @Diwyansh Thank you I have just editing the question for practice purposes. I will have a look at the other answer.

Comment: Sure try your best let me know once if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your main as:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WheelProvider()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

your wheel provider class will look like:

```
class WheelProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

  int _selectedId = 0;

  int get selectedId{
    return _selectedId;
  }

  void setId(int id){
    _selectedId = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

your car class can be:

```
class car extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final wheelProvider =Provider.of<WheelProvider>(context);
    var wheelImage = [
      Image.asset('assets/wheel1.png'),
      Image.asset('assets/wheel2.png'),
    ];
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/golf.png'), //car
        wheelImage[wheelProvider.selectedId], //wheel
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

finally your button class to :

```
    class Buttons extends StatelessWidget {
      const Buttons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final wheelProvider =
        Provider.of<wheelProvider>(context, listen: false);
        return Row(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){wheelProvider.setId(0)}, child: Text('Wheel 1')),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){wheelProvider.setId(1)}, child: Text('Wheel 2')),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

this is a basic flow for your provider.

Comment: Thank you , this has really helped me. I have had to rename a few of the variable names to help me understand. A quick question, why do we set the listen context to false in the Button class?

Comment: in button class the change in value of selected index has no impact and only propose of wheelProvider in button class is to change the value of selected index...listen can be kept false. Once listen kept false any change on selectedId will not recreate the widget